# Can I reduce these 3 ac adapters to one?

Tags: ac, relay

Scenario:  I'm (for fun) designing/building an automated irrigation system for a greenhouse.  There should be 3 solenoid valves, connected to a 4 channel, 5 volt relay, connected to a Raspberry Pi.

In the (admittedly, absolute childs-play) of a "circuit diagram" below, I have 3 ac adapters powering the 3 solenoids, each connected to the relays.

I'm fairly sure I do need three AC adapters so that the relays will work.. but is there some wiring arrangement I'm not thinking of to where I can "merge" the 3 ac adapters into one?

[image]

**Edit:**
[image]

Comment: What you are calling a "four channel relay" is a lot more than a relay. A raspberry pi can't drive a relay directly, and there's no such thing as a "four channnel relay"; that's just four relays.

Comment: run irrigation one zone at a time

Comment: Is the ``4 channel, 5 volt relay`` a board such as [AC250V, DC30V Electromechanical Relay Platform Evaluation Expansion Board](https://www.digikey.co.uk/en/products/detail/sunfounder/TS0011/18668621)? I.e. something designed to allow relays to be driven by a GPIO on an microcontroller. If so, can you [edit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/705524/edit) the question to include a link to the datasheeet.

Answer (score 1):

You can break the + side of a suitably-sized AC adaptor  (enough to power all three solenoids with some buffer) out to the common terminal of each relay, tie the grounds back together at the adaptor and the solenoids will switch separately. Since you are using relays, the ground between the solenoids and the rest of the circuit doesn't need to be (and in my opinion, should not be) shared but for the sake of your relays' contacts don't forget your flyback diodes.

Answer (score 1):

The second schematic will work if either the AC adapter is capable of supplying enough current to power all the solenoids, or the microcontroller takes care to only activate the number of solenoids the adapter can power but not more.

Note you could put freewheeling diodes on the solenoids to prevent relay contact arcing at turn-off. This will prolong the life of your relays.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please update your question with more information about the AC adapters and the solenoid valves.  After all, that is what your questions are about.  Voltages, currents, powers - anything?

Absent that, an answer depends on assumptions.  Let's assume that all of the solenoid valves operate on the same AC voltage as the adapters.  Then the question becomes one of currents.  What is the operating current of one valve, and what is the max continuous output current of one adapter?

Lastly, how many valves will be on at the same time?  If it is only one, then things should work as shown in your second schematic.  If it is more than one, then does the total simultaneous valve current exceed the rating of the AC adapter?  If no, then the second schematic should work.  If yes, then you are back to the first one.

Answer (score 0):

A single adaptor should do, provided that its maximum output current is much larger than the total current of the three solenoids.

Here's the schematic.

[image]